# "Message : Undefined Variable:query " error on joining two tables codeigniter mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, html-table

I have two tables named 'addexpense' and 'addcategory' .
I have successfully joined each of the tables but on my view page the data are not viewing and an error message is passed on the screen. Please help.

**This is my model**

```
public function getExpenses(){
 $this->db->select("addexpense.exp_date, addexpense.exp_amount, addexpense.exp_note, addexpense.exp_created, addcategory.category_name");
 $this->db->from('addexpense');
 $this->db->join('addcategory', 'addcategory.category_id = addexpense.category_id');
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result();
}
```

**This is my Controller**

```
public function join(){
  $query = $this->base_model->getExpenses();
  //$data['result'] = null;
    if($query)
    {
        $data['query'] =  $query;
    }
  $this->load->view('listexpense', $data);
}
```

**This is my view code**

```
<tr>
    <td><strong>Date</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Amount</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Note</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Created</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Category Name</strong></td>
</tr> 
<?php foreach($query as $expenses){?>
<tr>
    <td><?=$expenses->exp_date;?></td>
    <td><?=$expenses->exp_amount;?></td>
    <td><?=$expenses->exp_note;?></td>
    <td><?=$expenses->exp_created;?></td>
    <td><?=$expenses->category_name;?></td>
</tr>     
<?php }?>
```

Comment: `$query = $this->base_model->getExpenses(); print_r($query ); exit;` check value comes from modal or not ?

Comment: yeah i alredy checked and tested through my controller page       function test()
     {
      $query = $this->base_model->getExpenses();
      foreach ($query as $query)
      {
       echo $query->exp_date;
       echo $query->exp_amount;
       echo $query->exp_note;
       echo $query->exp_created;
       echo $query->category_name;
      }
     }

Comment: what is the result . did you getting the values ?

Comment: @JYoThI Iam have getting my data correctly, from both table as i wanted ,,,,,,  **2017-08-07250trtrgvdfdfdfTea Expanse Edappal2017-08-081000gcfddfcgdfdfcfHarithaRent Edappal Shop**

Comment: Share your error message which you are getting on screen.

Comment: try my code and see the result.if you get any error show me the recent erro

Comment: what is error that you getting?

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: query

Filename: views/listexpense.php

Line Number: 82                                                                                                  A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/listexpense.php

Line Number: 82

Comment: @user7596840  A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: query

Comment: In controller have you tried `var_dump($query);` and checked data..?

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya how to use `var_dump($query);` inside my controller. can u please specify that .....

Comment: After this line in controller `$query = $this->base_model->getExpenses();` add this lines `var_dump($query);die;` and share output.

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya still that error message is popping

Comment: You need to add this entire line `var_dump($query);die;` . Have you added `die;` in controller like I mentioned in above comment.?

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya yeah friend i know it, i done it .still no hope

Comment: @Yahiya : Check my answer below.

Comment: Maybe rename the variable to some thing `$data['listexpense']` of course change on foreach on view as well

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya nothing changed friend

Comment: @Yahiya I have added answer

Comment: @wolfgang1983 **Message: Undefined variable: listexpense**

Comment: @wolfgang1983 i checked it , still popping error **undefined variable**

Comment: Any chance you are using AJAX there?

Comment: @Tpojka ??? I didn't get your answer.

Comment: It is not answer, it is subquestion: do you use AJAX in view file or just make PHP request? I asked, because, if you use AJAX, AJAX is expecting string to be returned instead view load.

Comment: @Tpojka no, not in this page

Answer (score 1):

set controller function this way

```
   public function join(){
      $data['query'] = $this->base_model->getExpenses();
      $this->load->view('listexpense', $data);
    }
```

Comment: Still that error message is notifying on the screen @parvez

Comment: `public function join(){
         $data['query'] = $this->base_model->getExpenses();
         $this->load->view('listexpense', $data);
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Please can you check your data is going on view file or not by printing it at start of your view

```
<?php echo '<pre>';
 print_r($query);
 ?>
```

Comment: Yes it is passing, I used the code, `function test()
     {
      $query = $this->base_model->getExpenses();
      foreach ($query as $query)
      {
       echo $query->exp_date;
       echo $query->exp_amount;
       echo $query->exp_note;
       echo $query->exp_created;
       echo $query->category_name;
      }
     }`               @user7596840

Comment: print your data on view means on html file at start of html page not in controller's function

Comment: i also done ur code in my view page, still that error is popping with an different style

Comment: no @user7596840 , the error is like this **A PHP Error was encountered



Severity: Notice


Message:  Undefined variable: query


Filename: views/listexpense.php


Line Number: 76**

Comment: change variable name $query and then check once

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not initialized `model` in `controller`.

In your `controller` you need to load `model` first before using its `properties`. Please check below for your controller method.

```
public function join() {
    $this->load->model('base_model');
    $query = $this->base_model->getExpenses();
    $data = array();
    if ($query) {
        $data['query'] = $query;
    }
    $this->load->view('listexpense', $data);
}
```

Let me know still it not works.

Comment: still no hope friend

Comment: Use suggestion mentioned by @wolfgang1983, It might be due to same variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Model change result() to result_array()

```
public function getExpenses(){
    $this->db->select("addexpense.exp_date, addexpense.exp_amount, addexpense.exp_note, addexpense.exp_created, addcategory.category_name");
    $this->db->from('addexpense');
    $this->db->join('addcategory', 'addcategory.category_id = addexpense.category_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Controller try code below

```
public function join()
{
    $results = $this->base_model->getExpenses();

    $data['expenses'] = array();

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $data['expenses'][] = array(
            'exp_date' => $result['exp_date'],
            'exp_amount' => $result['exp_amount'],
            'exp_note' => $result['exp_note'],
            'exp_created' => $result['exp_created'],
            'category_name' => $result['category_name']
        );
    }

    $this->load->view('listexpense', $data);

}
```

View make sure is the correct view

```
<table>
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($expenses as $expense){?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $expense['exp_date'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $expense['exp_amount'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $expense['exp_note'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $expense['exp_created'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $expense['category_name'];?></td>
</tr>     
<?php }?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: **A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: expenses

Filename: views/listexpense.php

Line Number: 79**

Comment: @Yahiya Must be some thing else you might be loading the same view in another function that is causing it. It all should work works on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code please check and update
**Model**

```
public function getExpenses(){
   $this->db->select("addexpense.exp_date, addexpense.exp_amount, addexpense.exp_note, addexpense.exp_created, addcategory.category_name");
   $this->db->from('addexpense');
   $this->db->join('addcategory', 'addcategory.category_id = addexpense.category_id');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   $query_rows = $query->num_rows();
   if($query_rows > 0){
          return $query->result();
   } else{
          return 0;
   }
}
```

**For Controller**

```
public function join(){
    $this->load->model('base_model');
    $query = $this->base_model->getExpenses();
    //print_r($query);die();
    $data['query'] = '';
    if($query != 0){
            $data['query'] = $query;
    }

    $this->load->view('listexpense', $data);
}
```

**For View**

```
<tr>
    <td><strong>Date</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Amount</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Note</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Created</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Category Name</strong></td>
</tr> 
<?php
    if($query != ''){ 
    foreach($query as $expenses){?>
        <tr>
        <td><?=$expenses->exp_date;?></td>
        <td><?=$expenses->exp_amount;?></td>
        <td><?=$expenses->exp_note;?></td>
        <td><?=$expenses->exp_created;?></td>
        <td><?=$expenses->category_name;?></td>
    </tr>     
<?php } }?>
```

remove the comment "//print_r($query);die();" and check that whether the model is sending the data or not and please update..